# How to use conditions on params in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters

I have an `ownership` model that belongs to a `product` model and to a `user` model.

An `ownership` has the following parameters :

- user_id (integer)
- product_id (integer)
- owning_date (datetime)
- given_date (datetime)
- current (boolean)
- agreed (boolean)

A user is the owner of a product when current is true. current is true when owning_date is not nil, and given_date is nil.

I have an `update` method in my **ownership controller** that is defined like this :

```rb
def update
    @ownership = Ownership.find(params[:id])
    @ownership.update_attributes(ownership_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        flash[:success] = t('flash.success.ownership.update')
        redirect_to product_path(@ownership.product)
      end
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I created an **agree button** and a **take button** :

```rb
<%= form_for(ownership, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :agreed, value: true %></div>
  <%= f.submit "agree" %>
<% end %>


<%= form_for(ownership, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :owning_date, value: Time.now %></div>
  <%= f.submit "take" %>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to change the update method in my controller because when the user click on the **take button**, the given_date of the previous ownership must be changed to `Time.now`. But I don't want my update method to do that when the user click on the **agree button**.

I tried the following code but it didn't worked. After clicked on the button, there was two ownerships with current for the same product.

```rb
  def update
    @ownership = Ownership.find(params[:id])
    if @ownership.owning_date != params[:owning_date]
      @ownership.product.ownerships.find_by(current: true).update_attributes(given_date: Time.now, current: nil)
    end
    @ownership.update_attributes(ownership_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        flash[:success] = t('flash.success.ownership.update')
        redirect_to product_path(@ownership.product)
      end
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to check witch form is submitted and do some action depending on user's choice?

Simple check like this in `OwnershipCcontroller#update`

```
if params[:commit] == 'take'
  # do some action
else
  # do another action
end
```

Comment: Ooops, it didn't worked... I still have two current ownerships for only one user... Can you explain a bit the code I should write ?

Comment: Try to debug what attributes and values received to update action when you click `agree` or `take`. And can you share your `update` action code?

Comment: OK, I found a way. The server rendered `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "ownership"=>{"owning_date"=>"2013-07-16 11:57:55 +0200"}, "commit"=>"take", "id"=>"335"}`. So I delete your `choice: 'take'`, and instead of calling `params[:choice]`, I called `params[:commit]`.
Do you want to update your answer ?

Comment: Ok, this is also a good solution. I'll update my answer. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you remove your first solution, because it's not very clear for the future viewers of this page ;-)